# Distribution over topics for LDA using Gensim

Tags: gensim, lda

I have trained a Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) model on a corpus of documents using the [gensim package](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) in python.

I am able to retrieve the following:

1. Distribution of topics over **one document**
2. Distribution of words in a topic

However, how can we obtain the distribution over topics (probability of a topic) in the **entire corpus**?

For example, if we 3 topics can be get a distribution as follows for the entire corpus (not just one document): 
[topic 1: 0.5, topic 2: 0.3, topic 3: 0.2]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: not an answer, but a question: how do you get the _entire_ distribution over one document? If I use `lda[corpus[i]]`, I only get the top 3 or 4 topics contributing to document `i` with the rest of the topic weights being 0.0. however I know that LDA should produce a topic distribution for all topics for every document.

Comment: @killerT2333 the default minimum_probability in gensim is 0.01, so any topics with a probability lower than that is not returned.